# Grid Missing in Edit and Object Mode

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I just updated to Blender 3.5.1 and I realized that the grid that is present in start up is gone, and I am unable to find a way to bring it back.

I have opened the Viewport Overlay menu and check and unchecked the box, but it is grayed out. When I uncheck the box for Grid, it only hides the X and Y axis lines for some reason. I have the Viewport Overlay turned on, the grid is not a new color that is blending into the background, I have tried what I think was uninstalling and reinstalling the whole program.

I have also tried going to Orthographic mode and that hasn't fixed the problem either.

I am at a loss for anything other than it being a bug in the newest version of Blender. Does anyone have another suggestion for what I might try?

Here is an image it took directly upon startup, and an image with the Viewport Overlay menu open.

It is more of a nagging problem in my mind than an actual workflow deal, but I just want to know how to fix it as I get familiar with the interface.

[image] [image]

Comment: I've had the same problem, going to File->Defaults->Load Factory settings brings back the grid. No idea what does this, i was suspecting blenderkit plugin but i can't seem to recreate the problem now.